# Autocompile SASS stylesheet when a partial stylesheet is changed

Tags: css, ruby, windows, compilation, sass

I've just started working on a project using SASS on a windows machine. The main stylesheet (styles.scss) inports several partials (_typography.scss etc), and styles.scss is watched by sass and gets automatically compiled to styles.css.

On a mac, any changes to the partials results in styles.scss getting recompiled, but on a pc I have to save styles.scss itself in order to get SASS to compile it. Is there a way I can get a pc to behave the same as a mac?

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem.

My file structure looked like this:

```
website-root
    _dev
        _some-partial.scss
        _stuff.scss
        main.scss
    css
        main.css
    js
        ...
    watchSass.bat
    ...
```

I keep my .scss files inside _dev, and compile them out into the css folder.

My previous batch file looked like this:

```
sass --watch "_dev\main.scss":"css\main.css"
```

I simply changed it to watch the entire folder, not the specific file, like this:

```
sass --watch "_dev":"css"
```

Now changing any .scss file causes the non-partials to be recompiled (in turn recompiling the partials they include).

Thanks to user `hlb` on freenode #sass for helping me sort that out!

Comment: Also you probably don't need the quotes around the folder paths, my folder structure was actually a lot more convoluted than that